# How would I go about uploading a user-chosen file to a folder in my Google Drive using Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

Basically, I want the user to be able to select one of their images, upload it, and then have it saved to a particular folder in my Google Drive. Here is what I have so far on the HTML/Javascript side...

```html
<form>
Photo: <input type="file" name="photo" id="p" accept="image/png, image/jpeg"><br>
<input type="button" onClick="formSubmit()" value="Add">
</form>
<script>
function formSubmit() {
var pic = document.getElementbyId("p").value;
google.script.run.doPost(pic);
}


</script>
```

...and this is what I have on the Google app script side...

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');

}
function doPost(pic) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1bMuxCecrBRo8fToRRvW6q7S9_9OUQHV1');
  folder.createFile(pic);
  
}
```

I'm quite new to Google App script and javascript, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028646/http-post-and-google-apps-script-file-upload)

Comment: Have you considered an alternative of Google Forms for files uploading? This way an uploaded file will be targeted directly to Google Drive and you can use Form Submit event to move it to another folder as desired.

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax error: It should be `document.getElementById("p").value` instead of `document.getElementbyId("p").value` (capital "B").